# Activate only AJAX feature in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I really like jQuery mobile's AJAX and caching features. I'm building an app at the moment and only want to include these specific features. Including jQuery mobile into my web app (css + js) completely and utterly breaks my layout.

I've tried only including the CSS that is required for this functionality but it's hard to determine what is required and what isn't.

Has anyone tried this before? If so, any tips?

Answer (score -1):

There is an option to build custom library using http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Comment: this builder does not have options to only include the AJAX and caching features, as specified in the question

Comment: I have just used this in one of my application. Select only the options in 'Navigation' section, which brings AJAX loading and caching features. There is a problem with custom css therefore page will not appear, to solve this issue, include jquery.mobile.structure.css